# draw program for LEGO MOC models?

Tags: moc

I want to design a MOC digitally. I can do this with ldraw, but
are there any drawing programs better than ldraw to make models of LEGO ?

kind regards,
Peter

Comment: Why not use the Lego digital designer (http://ldd.lego.com/nl-nl/)?

Comment: @nebu support for this program has been ended.  http://www.brothers-brick.com/2016/01/21/lego-digital-designer-officially-defunded-and-unsupported-news/

Comment: I've found LDD to be effective under MacOS.

Answer (score 4):

Even though support has ended, the [LDD software](http://ldd.lego.com) still works. Alternatively, you mention LDraw but LDraw is only a catalogue and a standard - there are different software packages that allow you to draw on top of the LDraw catalog such as MLCad and LEOCad - have you tried these to see which one works? I use MLCad extensively - it looked daunting at first but the tutorials at [http://www.holly-wood.it](http://www.holly-wood.it/mlcad/basic1-en.html) helped a ton - worth spending a few hours doing those tutorials.

As per @Philo's suggestion: another program worth looking at is [LDCad](http://www.melkert.net/LDCad), which promises to be more convenient and more powerful than MLCad or LEOCad.

Comment: I would suggest to give a try to LDCad, also using LDraw parts library, it is MUCH more convenient and powerful than MLCad (and LeoCAD that I used before). http://www.melkert.net/LDCad

Answer (score 3):

I found [BrickLink Studio](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/download.page) quite good, but only worked with LEGO Digital Designer (LDD) before. Has also the ability to create instructions as PDF, though the process of creating all the steps is manual. Missing parts can be added by exporting them from LDD or placing additional LDraw models in a specific program folder. Comes also with an additional program ([Part Designer](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/partdesigner.page)) to create custom bricks or to put custom pattern on existing bricks or minifigs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the Google LEGO building app that you can use to design LEGO sets and MOCs.

Here is the link:

https://www.buildwithchrome.com/builder#pos=170623x401445&load=ahFzfmJ1aWxkd2l0aGNocm9tZXIsCxIFQnVpbGQiIXRpbGV4XzE3MDYyM190aWxleV80MDE0NDVfem9vbV8yMAw

I hope this helps.

Comment: As of March 2019, the Google Lego Chrome site has been closed.