# LDD Seems to be missing a piece

Tags: instructions, ldd

So I'm trying to make an alternate version of the UCS Tie Fighter.  I'm following the official instructions downloaded from the LEGO site, and I've come in to a problem.  This piece, seen here (ID: 6089147 from the piece list) is missing from the LDD parts:
[image: The part in question]

[image: Where is it??]

Now, I'm not sure if this is the best place to mention this, but well... there it is.
If it's in some weird place that I haven't looked it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction, but as it stands I'm pretty sure it just isn't in the list.  How would one go about telling the big wigs about this?

Comment: You talking about the yellow piece?

Answer (score 4):

18677 IS in latest LDD update (mid march 2016), issued after announcement of LDD end of support... Just make sure to be in LDD Extended mode to find it, along with other plates.

Answer (score 3):

I think this has to do with the fact that part [18677 Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Bottom](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=18677#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) is a new part (has only been in production since 2015) whereas its counterpart [11458 Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Top](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=11458#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) has been around since 2013. Couple that with the fact that [LEGO recently announced the end of maintenance for LEGO Digital Designer (Brickset Article)](http://brickset.com/article/18789/rip-ldd) with this explicit mention:

> ... but please do not expect any updates regarding functionality, **the adding of new LEGO elements** or glitch fixes.

It is likely that this part will never be added to LDD - you would need to switch over to an LDraw-based modeling tool such as mentioned in [the answers to this question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7422/draw-program-for-lego-moc-models/7423#7423).

Answer (score -1):

[image]I just saw this part in my LDD, try the extended mode

Comment: Please use a photo editor to circle the part you're talking about.